# IIS Password prompt for given folder ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, iis

How can I configure IIS to prompt for passwords on a web application running on ASP.NET MVC in IIS?

I want to password protect the `Views\ApplicationLog\` folder, so that browsers ask for username and password when users try to access this folder.

How could I accomplish this? Can this be done directly from IIS, or do I need to set something in web.config?

Please try to be thorough, I don't know IIS all that well.

Comment: In production, we have IIS 6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using MVC, you shouldn't have anyone directly accessing anything under your `Views` folder at all.  Instead, your `Controllers` (or their actions) will assert whatever authentication is required.

In this specific case, it looks like your controller is named `ApplicationLogController`.  So you'd add an `[Authorize]` attribute on the controller as follows, and it will automatically ensure that anyone accessing the controller methods is authorized.

```
[Authorize] // You can also do [Authorize(Roles="MyRole,YourRole")], etc...
public class ApplicationLogController : Controller
{
...
}
```

Comment: I did this, but it doesn't prompt users for credentials, it just boots them.

Comment: DO you have authentication set up in your web app?  I.e. with the login page URL, etc.?

Comment: No. In fact I got it working in IIS 7.5, but in 6.0 it happily serves the page to everyone. Even when I've disabled everything from anonymous login to windows authentication.

Comment: If you're willing, could you post the relevant portions of web.config?  (The `authentication` and `membership` elements)  Also make sure you don't have impersonation turned on.

Comment: None of those are even declared

Comment: That's probably why IIS6 isn't enforcing it, then - it's not configured to do so.

Answer (score 0):

In the IIS 6 manager, go to the "Directory Security" tab, click on "Edit" then check "Integrated Windows Authentication" and / or "Basic Authentication" depending on the modes you want to support.

In system.web within your app's web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```